# How to prevent JFrame/EXIT_ON_CLOSE from killing the nrepl server?

Tags: emacs, clojure, nrepl

**EDIT** Using DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE is not what I'm after, because them I've got the "inverse" problem: the REPL stays alive when I close the JFrame (which is good) but then it *also* stays alive when launced from outside the REPL (which is bad).

I'm writing a Swing application in Clojure and I find it convenient to both test thing from the REPL (*nrepl* under Emacs) and from outside the REPL (for example by using `lein run` or by running the standalone *.jar*).

When I'm not launching my Swing application from the REPL, I find it convenient to set the default close operation to be EXIT_ON_CLOSE.  For example:

```
 (.setDefaultCloseOperation jframe JFrame/EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
```

So I can click on the JFrame's close button and be done with my app.

However apparently (I may be mistaken on this but I think I'm not seeing things) this is problematic when run from the REPL: as soon as I click on the JFrame's close button I apparently kill the *nrepl* server and have to reopen a new *nrepl*.

Knowing that I need to both test from *nrepl* and from outside any REPL, how can I solve my problem?

Should I "detect" that I'm run from a REPL and then not set the default close operation to exit?  Or?

Answer (score 0):

`JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE` exits the application by calling `System.exit()` which [terminates the currently running Java virtual machine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exit%28int%29). Since both your application and the REPL run inside the same JVM (since you've started your app from the REPL), this means that the REPL will get killed as well.

Instead, try using:

```
(.setDefaultCloseOperation jframe JFrame/DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)
```

This will also hide (and dispose) the JFrame when you click its close button, but keep your JVM -- and hence your REPL -- running.

Comment: I fully know that... The problem is that if I do that when I run my app from outside a REPL (say directly from the terminal), then the app doesn't close when I click on the close button!

Comment: Yeah, I know. I've been playing a little bit with trying to hack around it but couldn't get it done properly. Sorry, I think for now that's the best you can do. :-/

Answer (score 0):

Use an environment variable when starting your REPL and choose whether to do dispose on close or exit onclose depending on that variable.

When launch standalone, the variable check would fail and you can thus do exit on close.

Edit:

In the shell:

```
export REPL_MODE=true ; lein repl
```

In the clojure code:

```
(def repl-mode (System/getenv "REPL_MODE"))
(if (not (nil? repl-mode))
     ; in repl, set to dispose on close
     ; in standalone mode, set to exit on close
```

Comment: I could do that... Could you edit a bit your question to show how I could read that environment variable from Clojure?